# SELECT multiple rows with new ID counter value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table `SESSIONVARIABLES` that contains 250 rows. The table columns are

```
USERGROUP, ID, DESCRIPTION
```

I would like to create a `SELECT` statement (to use in an `INSERT` into `SESSIONVARIABLES`) that returns a row for each distinct `USERGROUP` (there will be 13) with the ID being the current maximum plus one incremented for each row

So ideally something like

```
251 | UserGroup1
252 | UserGroup9
253 | UserGroup25
254 | UserGroup33
255 | UserGroup44
256 | UserGroup100
```

and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run on from the current max id:

```
select
    max(USERGROUP),
    row_number() over (order by USERGROUP) + (select max(id) from SESSIONVARIABLES)
from SESSIONVARIABLES
group by USERGROUP
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. So is wrapping the USERGROUP in a MAX() statement superflous?

Comment: you can remove the max

Answer (score 1):

The code below calculates the max of the current table, and then uses a ROW_NUMBER to determine the next sequential id values.

```
DECLARE @SessionVariables TABLE (USERGROUP VARCHAR(100), ID INT, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @SessionVariables VALUES
    ('UserGroup1', 250, NULL),
    ('UserGroup9', 249, NULL),
    ('UserGroup25', 248, NULL),
    ('UserGroup33', 247, NULL),
    ('UserGroup44', 246, NULL),
    ('UserGroup100', 245, NULL)

--INSERT @SessionVariables (ID, USERGROUP)
    SELECT 
        MaxID.ID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SV.USERGROUP) AS [ID],
        SV.USERGROUP
    FROM @SessionVariables SV
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @SessionVariables) MaxID (ID)
    GROUP BY
        SV.USERGROUP,
        MaxID.ID
```

This yields output:

```
ID                   USERGROUP
-------------------- ------------------
251                  UserGroup1
252                  UserGroup100
253                  UserGroup25
254                  UserGroup33
255                  UserGroup44
256                  UserGroup9
```